# PHP Threading Explained

Tags: php, multithreading, client-server, client

In any given PHP page, if one 'echoes' a given piece of information, it will be sent to a certain user, and no others. What exactly decides which client receives the data, and can this be changed? Furthermore, could one use a single script to send data to multiple clients?

Comment: more about the web-server than php. " Furthermore, could one use a single script to send data to multiple clients" any web page behaves in that way, one file, many clients

Comment: need user login and manage it by session

Comment: So if, say, a certain user was using a certain login stored in a session variable, even if a script knew the session variable, how could it send data to that specific user?

Comment: the browser sends the session id to the server with every request

Comment: Here's a better example. Could one script send content to multiple clients with one use of the script

Comment: yes, what are you actully trying to do ?

Comment: Handle a chat application from a single script, similar to how it would be done from node.js, as that is a more efficient approach for websocket connections.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No

---

## Long answer:

When you connect to a WebServer, the web server responds by sending you a piece of data. In this case your 'echo'. Then the connection is closed and its history.

**Theoraticly** it is possible to send one piece of data to multiple clients as long as they are connected to the webserver. i.e their web browser shows 'loading page'

**Practically**, its not possible, because once a connection is closed, the user has to hit the refresh button again to connect to the server and fetch new data

I suggest you read this fantatic article which will give you a broad sense on how web servers work.
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/web-server.htm